# Why VAE Encoder outputs log variance and not standard deviation?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

When talking about `VAE` (and viewing `VAE` implementations),  the Encoder outputs:

μ, log(variance)

when we train the model (the part of the `decoder model)`, we convert the `log(variance)` to Standard deviation:

```
std = exp(0.5 * logvar)
```

(I took the example from here: https://github.com/AntixK/PyTorch-VAE/blob/master/models/vanilla_vae.py)

If we need to convert the `log(variance)` to `Standard deviation,` why won't we output the Standard deviation from the encoder instead of making calculation to convert it to Standard deviation ?

Comment: This is not a programming problem, you should ask it in the AI Stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

A quite complete answer has been given by user166243 on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353220/why-in-variational-auto-encoder-gaussian-variational-family-we-model-log-sig) (a place more accurate for such non-programming questions). In short, as stated in the answer of DMcC, it improves numerical stability.

> it brings stability and ease of training. by definition sigma has to
> be a positive real number. one way to enforce this would be to use a
> ReLU funtion to obtain its value, but the gradient is not well defined
> around zero. in addition, the standard deviation values are usually
> very small 1>>sigma>0. the optimization has to work with very small
> numbers, where the floating point arithmetic and the poorly defined
> gradient bring numerical instabilities.
>
> if you use the log transform, you map the numerically unstable very
> small numbers in [1,0] interval to [log(1), -inf], where you have a
> lot more space to work with. calculating log and exp are numerically
> stable and easy, so you basically gain space where your optimization
> variable can move within.
>
> please do not confuse: people do not use the log(sigma) value as the
> sigma value, but always transform it back to the original space. also
> in VAEs, you need the log(sigma) value in the Kullback-Leibler
> divergence term, so you need to calculate it anyways...

Comment: There is no point to bring answers from other sites here, as the question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Learning log(var) improves training stability.

Comment: Why ? How does it improve ?

Comment: It ensures the variance is positive, which it must be. Additionally, the variance is typically much smaller than 1 so it maps it to a much bigger range which makes finding a suits value easier for the network.